# Does this volatility-like measure have a name?

Tags: volatility, terminology

So, basically I'm looking at `{=SQRT(AVERAGE((R1:R100)^2))}`, or in words: the square root of the average of squared daily returns.

Is there a nice simple term/name for this? (By simple term, I mean a word that I could use with non-statisticians and the like.)

Comment: I suppose it is the RMS (root mean square) return, but that term is not in widespread non-technical use  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square

Comment: In statistical term this is a square root of second general moment, i.e. $\sqrt{E(X^2)}$. Could you provide more details? For which calculation do you use this measure? Afer that I would come with *laymen explanation* your are looking for.

Comment: Just one comment, the measure seems not to express volatility as there is no *base* you are measuring difference against (like an average in standard deviation).

Comment: @noob2 I just might use 'quadratic mean' mentioned in the Wikipedia article. Thanks

Comment: @MartinVesely I'm not looking for a layman explanation. (I have that.) But, rather, I'm looking for a good term/name for the measure to use after having explained it.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume a zero drift for our asset return, this formula is indeed simply a measure for (daily?) volatility.

Comment: Thanks. I know. One of my own thoughts was to call it 'zero-drift volatility'.

Comment: I believe one can show that ‘zero drift volatility’ is the same as ‘regular volatility’ in the limit of small time steps.

Comment: @dm63 That is indeed what I see over longer periods. But in this case, I'm using the measure for time periods that are small themselves. For example, six days of -2% each. Then the two measures are quite different.

Comment: @keep these mind, I agree with that.